# Does PLSQL in DB2 support nested while statemnts?

Tags: sql, plsql, db2

I have a following query for DB2 database:

```sql
    BEGIN
        DECLARE NUMBER_OF_ROWS INT;
        DECLARE ITER_INDX_1 INT;
        DECLARE ITER_INDX_2 INT;
        SET ITER_INDX_1 = 0;
        SET ITER_INDX_2 = 0;
        SET NUMBER_OF_ROWS = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LOOPS.LTV_BEISPIEL);
        WHILE ITER_INDX_1 < NUMBER_OF_ROWS DO
            WHILE ITER_INDX_2 < NUMBER_OF_ROWS DO
                INSERT INTO LOOPS.TEST VALUES (1);
                SET ITER_INDX_2 = ITER_INDX_2 + 1;
            END WHILE;
            SET ITER_INDX_1 = ITER_INDX_1 + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END
    ;
```

`NUMBER_OF_ROWS` variable id set to 10 after querying the COUNT statement. As there are two WHILE statement, and one of them is nested, this code must produce 10*10=100 inserts, but for some reason it does only 10 inserts. Is there is an error in my logic or it is a bug in DB2?

Comment: PL/SQL is the name for Oracle's stored procedures. DB2 simply has _stored procedures_.

Comment: @jarlh: that's not entirely correct. DB2 also supports Oracle's PL/SQL if you enable certain compatibility configurations

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, cool. I had never heard of that before. Thanks!

Comment: I'd heard about that ([DB2 PL/SQL compatibility mode](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053610.html)), but the code above isn't much like PL/SQL.

Comment: Side question: Why loops?  SQL is made for "set" math, and the normal way to do this is to generate the set via a recursive CTE (or a premade numbers table).  Although whether your version of DB2 supports a CTE for an `INSERT` is an interesting question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not resetting `ITER_INDX_2` after the first loop:

```
        SET ITER_INDX_1 = ITER_INDX_1 + 1;
        SET ITER_INDX_2 = 0;
```

Hence, to answer your question:  This is a bug in your code.

To be honest, I would do this at the top of the loop:

```
   WHILE ITER_INDX_1 < NUMBER_OF_ROWS DO
        SET ITER_INDX_2 = 0;
        WHILE ITER_INDX_2 < NUMBER_OF_ROWS DO
            INSERT INTO LOOPS.TEST VALUES (1);
            SET ITER_INDX_2 = ITER_INDX_2 + 1;
        END WHILE;
        SET ITER_INDX_1 = ITER_INDX_1 + 1;
    END WHILE;
```